# Return jQuery object (instead of DOM) from jQuery array using index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing

I have a jQuery array of `<span>`s and I'd like to get just one of them as a jQuery object so that I can string additional methods on it. Something like `$mySpans[2]` (which returns a string), or `$mySpans.get(2)`, (which returns the DOM element directly).

I know that this will work:

```
$($mySpans[2]).someJQueryMethod( ... );
```

...but it seems a little redundant. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
$myspans.eq(2).method();
```

Comment: Why was this method named `eq`? That seems like an awful name. I know `index` also exists, but that should arguably have been `indexOf` or something

Comment: `eq` or "equals". `index` does something completely different. You can still use `slice` just like a regular array if that makes more sense.

Comment: How does `$myspans "equals" 2` make any sense? I understand that `index/indexOf` is traditionally used to search a collection and return an item's index, but even if `index` wasn't used, I just think a better name could be found.

Comment: @voithos Indeed, it's a poorly named method. There is no equivalent in the CSS spec so the jQuery authors were left to their own naming decisions, and clearly made a bad call. There are plenty of other examples of naming failures - for example $.grep() and $().filter() do the same thing but you have to use one or the other depending on whether you have some tags already selected.

Comment: I think it makes sense. It's modeled after the `:gt` and `:lt` selectors, so `:eq` makes complete sense to me. I read it as `select where index equals 2`

Answer (score 5):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/kan77/)***

You are going to want to use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/). Note that it will return the jQuery object wrapped element at that index, so if you only have one match you should use 0 (which follows that 2 will return the third of the set).

```
var $thirdMatch = $mySpans.eq(2);//== jQuery object with third match
var htmlElement = $thirdMatch[0];//== actual dom element
var matchedHtml = $thirdMatch.html();// call some jQuery API method
```

It is common practice when storing jQuery objects to use a `$variableName` for readability purposes.